# detectron2 - how to verify the number of images after augmentation?

Tags: detectron, image-augmentation

I can see that augmentations were applied but i can't see the resulted size of the training set. How can I check it? It's important because when calculating epochs, the dataset size after augmentation should be considered.

When I train a model using DefaultTrainer, there are few augmentations that are apllied by default. I get the following log prints:

```
[d2.data.datasets.coco]: Loaded 9034 images in COCO format from Datasets/full_train_coco.json
[d2.data.build]: Removed 6216 images with no usable annotations. 2818 images left.
[d2.data.dataset_mapper]: [DatasetMapper] Augmentations used in training: [ResizeShortestEdge(short_edge_length=(640, 672, 704, 736, 768, 800), max_size=1333, sample_style='choice'), RandomFlip()]
[d2.data.build]: Using training sampler TrainingSampler
[d2.data.common]: Serializing 2818 elements to byte tensors and concatenating them all ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of images is not being increased when augmentations are applied but stays the same, in your case 2818 images [(source)](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/4463).

Depending on the augmentation settings, the model might never "see" an original image, only augmented ones.
If you want to increase the size of training data, you'll need to write a custom function that augments data and saves both images and annotations in the format (COCO, LVIS...) you need. [This notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/julienbeaulieu/detectron2-wheat-detection-eda-training-eval?scriptVersionId=36552685&cellId=33) might help, in the Augmentation Visualization part, you can access both augmented images and bounding boxes and save them from there. Or use a library like [Albumentations](https://albumentations.ai/docs/).